# Where can I find beginner tutorials for the Arduino?

Tags: programming

I am new to all of this so anything is helpful.

Comment: There are hundreds of Arduino tutorials on the web (more than we could list here). A search engine should help you find them, and the [official Arduino website](http://www.arduino.cc/) is always a good place to start.

Comment: As above - PLUS load the Arduino IDE (you don'y have to own one) and on menu click Help then Reference. Each instruction is included with example code and explanations. Also in Help is "Getting Started" and "Frequently asked questions". Then in menu item File open "Examples" and you'll find many subfolders with working example code covering most areas.